# Make field/method accessible only to derived classes within same assembly?

Tags: c#, access-modifiers

On a public class in C# is there a way to make a field/method accessible only to derived classes within the same assembly?

From what I understand `protected internal` in C# means the same as `protected` *or* `internal` (ie accessible to derived classes *or* classes from the same assembly), which is not what I need.

Comment: C# does not support that, according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.isfamilyandassembly.aspx): _Methods with this visibility cannot be defined in Visual Basic or C#._

Answer (score 3):

What if you removed the "internal" only fields/methods from the public class to an internal class.  Then all of the classes in that assembly could derive from the internal class:

```
public abstract class MyClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

// Only classes in this assembly can derive from this class
internal abstract class InternalClass : MyClass
{
    protected string Other { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't prevent a class from an external assembly from compiling a call to it, but you can force an exception to occur at runtime if they do by putting this attribute on your protected member:

```
   [System.Security.Permissions.StrongNameIdentityPermission(
    System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.LinkDemand, 
    PublicKey = "...<Your assembly's full public key>...")]
```

Answer (score 1):

If the class is `internal`, there will be no way to sub-class it outside of the assembly.  Make the fields/methods `protected` and you're good to go.

If the class must be `public`, use an `internal` sub-class everywhere within your assembly.